# Getting marketcap from yahoo finance

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance

I have a very long list of stocks for which I'd like to get the market cap

say I have the following stocks stored as a list

```
test = ['A', 'AA', 'AA-W', 'AAAB', 'AAAG', 'AAAGY', 'AAAIF', 'AAALF', 'AAALY', 'AAAP', 'AAARF', 'AABA', 'AABB', 'AABC',
        'AABNF', 'AABVF', 'AAC', 'AAC', 'AAC-U', 'AAC-WS', 'AAC1', 'AACAF', 'AACAY', 'AACB', 'AACC', 'AACE', 'AACEU',
        'AACEY', 'AACH', 'AACIQ', 'AACMF', 'AACMZ', 'AACOU', 'AACPF', 'AACPU', 'AACQ', 'AACQU', 'AACQW']
```

How can I get the market cap with yahoo finance panda?

The code I am using now is the following, but it prints "Error with: ..." for each and every one of the stocks:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf

test = ['A', 'AA', 'AA-W', 'AAAB', 'AAAG', 'AAAGY', 'AAAIF', 'AAALF', 'AAALY', 'AAAP', 'AAARF', 'AABA', 'AABB', 'AABC',
        'AABNF', 'AABVF', 'AAC', 'AAC', 'AAC-U', 'AAC-WS', 'AAC1', 'AACAF', 'AACAY', 'AACB', 'AACC', 'AACE', 'AACEU',
        'AACEY', 'AACH', 'AACIQ', 'AACMF', 'AACMZ', 'AACOU', 'AACPF', 'AACPU', 'AACQ', 'AACQU', 'AACQW']
    
for ticker in test:
    try:
        marketCap = pdr.get_quote_yahoo(ticker)['marketCap']
        print(marketCap)
    except:
        print('Error with: ', ticker)
```

I tried pdr.get_quote_yahoo wrapper for a single stock and it works well, but not with the list that I'm using. What went wrong with my code?

The following works:

```
marketCap = pdr.get_quote_yahoo('A')['marketCap'])
print(marketCap)
```

Comment: You have an extra ")" in your "works" example that would cause it to fail, which makes me think this code isn't an exact copy/paste from what you're actually running.  Nothing looks wrong with the code you posted (looping through a list of strings vs passing a single string to the get_quote_yahoo method should have the same behavior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your code works, albeit with errors. Simple reason - many tickers don't correspond to any known stocks. My result for your code is as follows:

```
    A    44845838336
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    AA    6901355520
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    Error with:  AA-W
    Error with:  AAAB
    Error with:  AAAG
    Error with:  AAAGY
    Error with:  AAAIF
    AAALF    1551833984
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    AAALY    1662833024
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    Error with:  AAAP
    Error with:  AAARF
    Error with:  AABA
    AABB    46516112
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    Error with:  AABC
    Error with:  AABNF
    AABVF    31826214
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    AAC    1218749952
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    AAC    1218749952
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    Error with:  AAC-U
    Error with:  AAC-WS
    Error with:  AAC1
    AACAF    9106046976
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    AACAY    9020131328
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    Error with:  AACB
    Error with:  AACC
    Error with:  AACE
    Error with:  AACEU
    Error with:  AACEY
    Error with:  AACH
    Error with:  AACIQ
    Error with:  AACMF
    Error with:  AACMZ
    Error with:  AACOU
    Error with:  AACPF
    Error with:  AACPU
    AACQ    904719296
    Name: marketCap, dtype: int64
    Error with:  AACQU
    Error with:  AACQW
```

As you can see, to some you have values, and to most others you have errors. When I checked for a couple of tickers, in `finance.yahoo.com`, such as AA-W, AAAB, I don't see any stocks corresponding to that ticker symbol. For example, AACQW doesn't correspond to any known stocks, while AACQ (Equity NCM) and AACQU (Equity NMS) are. In fact, both AACQ and AACQU are for **Origin Materials Inc**.

There are some stocks for which yahoo APIs doesn't fetch results, but the web application of `finance.yahoo.com` fetches results. For example, the market cap of 904.719M for AACQ, you have the web result as follows:

[image: Web Results for AACQ]

For such stocks, you may want to use some web screen scraping apps to get results, but they may not be accurate (they might report the result such as 1.29T). Here is the [link](https://www.scrapehero.com/scrape-yahoo-finance-stock-market-data/) for one such app.